# Aggregate example sets in Rapidminer based on a specific attribute

Tags: union, aggregation, rapidminer

I am a bit stuck with a simple task of aggregating two example sets using rapidminer and need an advise on a process and possible operators.

I have two CSVs like:

```
key     A   B   C   D   E
first   2   2   2   2   2
second  3   3   3   3   3
```

and

```
key     D   E   F   G   H   I   J   K
first   4   4   4   4   4   99  99  99
third   5   5   5   5   5   77  77  77
```

What I want to have is an aggregated dataset which is basically a Union of these two, but also I would like to make the 'key' attribute a uniqie one in the resulting dataset. Since the 'first' value appears in both datasets, I need to sum the corresponding values, so the resulting dataset would be the following:

```
key     A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J   K
first   2   2   2   6   6   4   4   4   99  99  99
second  3   3   3   3   3   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?   ?
 third  ?   ?   ?   5   5   5   5   5   77  77  77
```

Note that 'First D' and 'First E' cells have become 6 (2+4).

Question marks are missing values as produced by the Union operator and will be replaced later.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with the `Union` operator.

With this input

```
key        B        C
first      4        5
third      4        5
```

and this

```
key        A        B
first      3        4
second     3        4
```

`Union` will do this.

```
key        A        B       C
first      3        4       ?
second     3        4       ?
first      ?        4       5
third      ?        4       5
```

Then use `Aggregate` to get this.

```
key        sum(A)   sum(B)  sum(C)
first      3        8       5
second     3        4       0
third      0        4       5
```

The parameters needed for this are `use default aggregation` set to `true`, `default aggregation function` set to `sum` and `group by attributes` set to `key`.

A final step is to use `Rename by Replacing` to change the attribute names to be more user friendly. The parameters needed are `replace what` set to `sum\((.*)\)` and `replace by` set to `$1`.

Comment: Will sure do that as soon as I have enough reputation :)

Comment: You should be able to accept the answer to indicate it answers your question.

Comment: Just did it! Thanks again for help :)